# iOS find word index

Tags: ios, objective-c

Suppose, I have a string in a `UITextView` that is :

```
NSString *str = @"Hello world. How @are you ? Hope that @you are @doing well. Can you @please suggest me?"
```

Here, in the above string there are 4 words that have a prefix "@". Now how can I find that count and their index? like:

```
(@are = 0,  @"you" = 1, @"doing" = 2, @"please"=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

get array of word starting with @. Index of word in array will it's index in string.

```
NSString *str = @"Hello world. How @are you ? Hope that @you are @doing well. Can you @please suggest me?";
NSMutableArray *atWordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *arrAllStr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

for (NSString *individualString in arrAllStr) {
    if ([individualString hasPrefix:@"@"]) {
        [atWordArray addObject:individualString];
    }
}

NSLog(@"There are %d word/s in string they are /n",atWordArray.count,atWordArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like,

```
    NSString *str = @"Hello world. How @are you ? Hope that @you are @doing well. Can you @please suggest me?";

NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSMutableArray *resultArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *resultArr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {


    if ([[[arr objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"@"]) {

        [resultArr addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];


    }

}

   // NSLog(@"result Arr : %@",resultArr);

for (int j = 0; j < resultArr.count; j++) {



    NSLog(@"%@ = %d",[resultArr objectAtIndex:j],j);
    NSDictionary *temp = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[resultArr objectAtIndex:j] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j]];
    [resultArr2 addObject:temp];
}


NSLog(@"array 2 : %@",resultArr2);
```